# ObjectContext instance per http request disposed after 1 query execution

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, objectcontext

I'm considering putting the ObjectContext inside HttpContext.Current so that all logic in the same request can access to it without having to open/destroy each time.
In ObjectContextManager class i created this.

```
get {
    string ocKey = "ocm_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x");
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(ocKey))
      HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(ocKey, new JEntities());
    return HttpContext.Current.Items[ocKey] as JEntities;
}
```

and then I call this static property every time i execute a query on current request.

```
public static JEntities CurrentObjectContext {
  get {
    if (ObjectContextManager == null)
      InstantiateObjectContextManager();
    return ObjectContextManager.ObjectContext;
    //return new JobsEntities();
  }
}
```

But it gets disposed when it tries to execute second query. 
Can you tell me where i went wrong?

Comment: are you executing the first query like `using(JEntities jEntities = ObjectContextManager.CurrentObjectContext){var entities = jEntities.Foo;}` ?

Answer (score 2):

Disposed? Your code has nothing to do with disposing. If you get disposed context it means you most probably enclosed the context retrieval into `using` and you disposed the instance yourselves.